# How to Set an Image as Background in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have two components:

1. `LoginLayout` which should is high order comp for Login component
2. `Login` component is page

I need to make the login page have an image as the background. 
I tried achieving this through CSS and it does not work.

**Here is `LoginLayout` comp:**

```
export default ({ children, title }) => (

// I tried to add background: url(.../img)) to this login-layout class
  <div className="login-layout">
    <Head>
      <title>Login to Tex</title>
    </Head>
    <div className="login-wrapper">{children}</div>
  </div>
);
```

**How can this be achieved in Next.js?**

Comment: Just checking that when you made the css rule, you ended the url() with the file extension e.g. `.png` or `.jpg`?

Comment: you can import css to your component like so `import './style.css'` at the top of your LoginLayout component

Comment: it's png, I am gonna check. 
@Deano yes impoted but didnt share that part of code.

Comment: Are you sure the image url is correct? You should probably use an absolute url to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your CSS attached to your component, as @Deano mentioned.

```
import './style.css';
```

If you use CSS modules import like this instead:

```
import styles from './MyStyles.module.css';

export default ({ children, title }) => (
  <div className={styles.loginLayout}>
    <Head>
      <title>Login to Tex</title>
    </Head>
    <div className={styles.Login-wrapper}>{children}</div>
  </div>
);
```